# Long polling ускорение?

Tags: jquery, php, long-poll, javascript

Написал примерчик чата на `Long Polling`, вероятно это дало некоторый прирост в производительности, но меня терзает множество вопросов.

1. Мой код вообще - `long polling`, ибо писал исходя из определения?
2. В моей версии сообщения обрабатываются медленно, как ускорить?
3. Когда длинный запрос ждет сообщения, то (несмотря на `usleep`(5000)), `while` успевает совершить много запросов (6m 37s - 166020), меня цифра пугает если честно, это нормально?  боюсь что даже 1000+ не выдержит, это так? (или мускул закэширует?)
4. Вопрос о правильности: я прерываю запрос перед отправкой сообщения и переспрашиваю, можно было этого не делать, но тогда все еще дольше (Велик шанс попасть в `usleep`). [уже понял, что мой перезапуск бессмыслен] Что делать, когда нужен перезапуск запроса чтобы сразу получить сообщение?
5. Если быстро отправлять сообщения (спамить), то некоторые, из-за `usleep` не показываются вовсе. Как это решить?

Код: https://gist.github.com/nikoncode/6383503
Демо: к сожалению на koding.com

Всем огромное спасибо за помощь.

Comment: исходя из того, что usleep ждет 5мс, выходит 200 запросов в секунду и за 6мин 37сек получилось бы не больше 79400 запросов. 

Но у Вас их больше. 418 в секунду. Но похоже ничего странного - просто не умеет он на таких маленьких задержках правильно отрабатывать (это предположение, нужно проверить).
Попробуйте задержку увеличить, сильно увеличить, до полусекунды хотя бы.

И после вывода данных пользователю добавьте какой-нибудь flush, а то браузер может ждать данных.

Comment: лучше всё по другому делать, во первых можно ждать события, это может быть какой-нибудь минисервер событий (получил событие, отослал всем заинтересованным(подключенным)), во вторых, такую штуку на php лучше не делать, т.к. каждый инстанс жрет очень много памяти, лучше сделать event driven сервер, на nodejs например или на C :) Всё это даст вам возможность не дергать mysql каждые 5мс, а получать сообщения по мере поступления.

Comment: @KoVadim, увеличивал время, тормоза не убираются. Ставил пол секунды. а под flush, что понимается, я просто не такой спец) Может в память писать?

Comment: @eicto спасибо, а можете дать линк почитать про это? Как я могу использовать событийное программирование при работе с бд, все равно дергать придется оттуда. Мне ведь хранить надо. Да и вообще это прототип, в бою это будут диалоги.

Comment: у node запросы к базе асинхронные, т.е. пришло событие ушел запрос, пришел ответ - послали реакцию.

Comment: так как я узнаю что в базе что-то новое, придется же постоянно обновлять. Или можно послать сигнал "есть новое" при отправке и достать, такая схема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не пойму одного: зачем каждый раз изобретать велосипед, если есть уже готовые решения?

Соглашусь с [@eicto](/users/11304/eicto), такие вещи лучше делать на NodeJS.

Если же хотите принципиально использовать PHP, то есть уже как [отдельные реализации](http://habrahabr.ru/post/128535/), так и готовые [фреймворки](http://habrahabr.ru/post/79377/) для этих целей.

А по поводу вашего кода, то могу сказать одно: чем дальше, тем больше будет тупить мускл. Я бы в него сливал просто копии сообщений, чтобы хранить историю, а все, что требует очереди - реализовал бы с использованием `memcache`, `redis` или `NoSQL` БД, например, на `MongoDB`.

И все таки посмотрите в сторону [проверенных решений](http://habrahabr.ru/company/ontico/blog/116211/), вместо изобретений велосипедов. Или у вас принцип? ))

Comment: Ну я бы использовал реализацию с хабра, но каюсь, я не понял принципа работы и как применить (помогите). Node.js Ковырял, но не думаю, что смогу написать такого рода приложение. А про PHPdaemon и не знал) Спасибо. Если можно поделитесь линкой как это сделать для диалогов между пользователями в связке с бд на nodejs. Спасибо.

Comment: Про NodeJS, думаю, лучше всего спросить @Artem Ryzhov - он на ней собаку уже съел ))

А от помощи, я думаю, он не откажет :)

Comment: А как привлечь его сюда?)

Comment: Блин, я забыл, что здесь нет личных сообщений )))
Отправил ему ссылку, думаю завтра он уже глянет :)

Comment: Спасибо, как как хабровариант http://habrahabr.ru/post/128535/ заставить работать, не подскажете. Раз уж пока, по Nodejs нет советов.

Comment: На сколько я понял, создаете объект класса `Polling`, методом `registerEvent` регистрируете нужные события, например, подключения, отправки сообщения etc., и запускаете процесс прослушки с помощью метода `listen`.

Для генерации событий используете метод `push`. Например, когда пользователь отправил сообщение, вы вызываете что-то в духе

    $polling_server->push('onNewMessage', $data)

где `$polling_server` - объект класса Polling, `onNewMessage` - имя события (придумываете своем и регаете через `registerEvent`, а $data - массив с данными (от кого, кому, время, сообщение и т.п.)

Comment: Надеюсь, вы разобрались с тем, что код самого класса находится [здесь][1] ))

  [1]:http://pastebin.com/af8hF88J

Comment: C тем, где находится код - я разобрался)) Попробую nodeJS утром.

Answer (score 0):

Действительно, в данном случае велосипеды плодить не нужно.
Успешно использую для решения такой и не только задачи [библиотечку SockJS](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client) - это кросбраузерное решение, которое самостоятельно выбирает технологию асинхронной передачи в зависимости от окружения.
Сервер сообщений реализован на node.js - все работает очень быстро и в основном устойчиво. Есть конечно некоторые недостатки на больших нагрузках, но достоинства все же перевешивают.
Рекомендую.